# Backup mongodb database from node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've been searching for an easy way for backing up an entire database in a simple step in node.js but surprisingly i din't find an easy to use module for this purpose.

The easiest solution I found on the net is using shelljs to run a shell mongodump command.

Is there any other way for making this task easy?

Comment: You wouldn't usually do admin stuff like this through Node - not sure what exactly you want to do through Node. Have a look at [Backup Methods](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/backups/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking about backing up to S3, perhaps this would work?
https://github.com/theycallmeswift/node-mongodb-s3-backup

Comment: yes, I saw that solution, interesting, but I am not backing up to S3.